# Waiting for PouchDB get to get a synced version from the server

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am using PouchDB to sync a database between a device and a server.

When installing my App on a new device I need to pull down the user's settings document from the server. If I do the following on a new device when the App has previously been run on another device and created the user settings:

```
var _DB = new PouchDB(localDBName);
_DB.sync(realRemoteDB, options);
_DB.get(userSettingsDocumentName);
```

The _DB.get says the document doesn't exist. If I wait long enough the sync works and the server docs are loaded locally and the .get works. How can I handle this other than putting in a long timeout?

Answer (score 2):

PouchDB functions are mostly asynchronous. This means that when you fetch the document, the sync might not be complete yet.

Here's how you should write it with promises:

```
var _DB = new PouchDB(localDBName);
_DB.sync(realRemoteDB, options).on('complete',function(info){
    //Sync is complete
    return _DB.get(userSettingsDocumentName);
}).then(function(doc){
    //Here you will have the document

}).catch(function(err){
    //An error occured
})
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis. I will try that in a couple of days.

Comment: The 'complete' never runs. If I add on 'change' that runs but not the 'complete'. The local database does sync with the remote database though.

Comment: What are your options?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by options?

Comment: The options passed to the sync? Are you doing a continuous sync?

Comment: Ah yes a live sync

Comment: So the live sync only complete when you request a cancel. What you should do  is : 
1. Make a singleshot sync to init your database
2. Get your document
3. Start a continuous synchronization

Comment: Thanks Alexis that makes sense